# Remove already exist object from array otherwise insert

Tags: javascript, object

Below javascript code for adding object to a javascript array. I want to add an object to array when it does not exist, if it already exists `object.rValue!= new object.rValue` then change `old rValue=new rValue`, otherwise same `rVale`. Also save it on array.
The problem is the object populate dynamically.

```
var arr = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rating").click(function() {
        var idx = $(this).closest('td').index();

        var userskill = {
            tech : $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.tech').text(),
            skill : $('#listTable thead th').eq(idx).text(),
            rValue : $(this).val()

        }
        validate(userskill);
    });

});

function validate(userskill) {

}
```

Comment: what I understood according to that I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
arr.forEach(function(elem){
    if(elem.rValue==newObj.rValue)
         elem.rValue = newObj.rValue;
})
```